# Autoplay video with sound: some websites still can do it

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I know almost browsers allow autoplay if:

1. video doesn't include sound
2. if video has sound, it must be muted
3. autoplay is allowed if user has a real gesture on the domain, such as click, tab, etc.
4. website have high scrore in Media Engagement Index which allow it to autoplay video with sound.

But as I see, some websites still bypass this rules, for example below one. It's not match any of above rules. It still auto play video with sound. Just F5 page, it is auto played with sound.

https://vieon.vn/truyen-hinh-truc-tuyen/

https://vieon.vn/truyen-hinh-truc-tuyen/vtv1-hd/

So in fact, in Javascript, is there any way to autoplay video including sound without having to set it muted?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In most modern web browsers, autoplaying videos with sound is generally not allowed unless certain conditions are met.
The conditions you mentioned, such as the video being muted or the user having interacted with the domain, are some of the common requirements for autoplaying videos with sound.

However, it's important to note that browser behavior and autoplay policies can vary, and there may be some exceptions or workarounds that certain websites employ to bypass these rules. These exceptions could be due to various factors, including specific browser settings, permissions granted by the user, or the website having a high Media Engagement Index score.

In JavaScript, there is no standard way to autoplay a video with sound without muting it. The autoplay behavior is controlled by the browser and its policies, and JavaScript alone cannot override these policies. It's always recommended to follow the autoplay guidelines and respect the user's preferences and privacy when implementing video autoplay on a website.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But my web is to provide OTT live stream and TV. The auto play without muted is better for user experience. User don't need to do extra action to unmute the video. Like the link I gave above, it's good for user.